# How can I use post method in ng2-smart-table whenever a new row is added?

Tags: angularjs, angular, post, ng2-smart-table

I used `ng2 smart table` in my angular 2 project, I need to send an `API` request using `http.post()` method when a new row is added to table. How can I get the value of each cell in the newly added row?

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
 <ng2-smart-table
[settings]="settings"
[source]="data"
(createConfirm)="onPostCall($event)"
(editConfirm)="onPostCall($event)">
</ng2-smart-table>
```

> For calling post method on both editing and creating new row

settings [TS]:

```
settings = {
     add: {
  confirmCreate: true,
     },
    edit: {
      confirmSave: true,
    },
    columns:{
      // your fields and titles here
     }
   }
```

On update[TS]

```
     onPostCall(event){
       event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
              // console.log(event.newData); //this contains the new edited data
           //your post request goes here
          //    example
       const req = http.post('/api/items/add', body);
        // 0 requests made - .subscribe() not called.
       req.subscribe();
      // 1 request made.
    }
```

Ref : https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/examples/various